# imputing two different computers into one sound input on a moniter

Tags: audio, cable

I am trying to put sound from two different computers (XP, and Win 7) into the same moniter.  Video is great but none of the sound splitters work.  Only of the female leads will work not both.  I have turned off the one non used computer but it only goes through one lead no matter what.  What si U need?  thanks . steve kastl

Comment: You might clarify with some pics or something maybe.

Answer (score 2):

You cant combine two audio outputs like that.  That could damage your sound cards.

The easiest thing would be to use an [audio mixer](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_st_price-asc-rank?keywords=audio%20mixer&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aaudio%20mixer&qid=1507767411&sort=price-asc-rank).

Some sound cards have "line in" which you can connect to the other sound card if it has an unamplified signal out.  It can work with an amplified signal, but distortion can occur, as you would be amplifying an amplified signal.